# How To Detect When UI Thread Starts and Stops Processing in WPF with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

In my WPF C# application, I have a little circle animation that I display while things are processing to let the user know that the application is "thinking" and they should just chill out.  It's a separate exe.  So, for example, when the user clicks a button to run analytics (which might take 5-10 seconds), I start the process to display the animation, and when it's all complete, I stop the process.  During this time, sub-threads have been newly spawned to handle background tasks. When completed the UI is updated, which can take a few seconds due to complex datagrids.

While this technically works, I'd rather approach it in a different manner.  I'd rather have the application auto-detect when the threads are working and automatically display the animation, and when the threads all complete, it stops displaying it.  I can detect the background threads easily, but how can I detect the UI thread?  I'd rather do it this way because there have been a couple of times that I accidentally missed killing the application and it was still running after processing completed.  This would prevent that.

Are there events that fire when the UI thread starts and stops?  If not, let's say I threw a timer in there that's fired every 1/2 second, is there a call I could make that would tell me the state of the UI thread?

Thanks

Comment: If you show us what you have so far, we could possibbly suggest different alternatives? Its hard to improve upon code that we cant see :(

Comment: you should better use a `BackgroundWorker` and run your time consuming process there. so you can start the animation before `DoWork` and stop it in `RunWorkerCompleted`

Comment: UI always work in main application's thread. You can do any long operations in different thread (backgroundworker, task etc.)

Comment: I probably didn't explain this well.  Much of the processing is on a background task.  There is some UI thread processing that occurs at the end, due to a large number of datagrids on multiple tabs that get reloaded, which can take a number of seconds to complete.  My animation is a seperate exe and is not run on the UI thread.  I know how to detect the state of a background thread, but I want to know how to detect the state of a UI thread.  That way, when all threads are complete I can stop the animation.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to *move* processing out of UI (for example with [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and let the background worker post notifications to the UI thread (started, progress update, finished).

Do not reinvent a wheel and move processing logic out of the UI thread.

Comment: The background tasks are often in a separate background thread.  But once completed, a number of large datagrids on different tabs have to reload, which would be on the ui thread.  That alone can often take a few seconds.

Comment: That's another problem (and mistake). You do not want to load loads of data at once. There are two reasons: firstly, it degrades user experience - nobody likes slow program ; secondly, pagination and search do this job with grace - you only load handful amount of data at once and allow user to search and go through the *pages*. Consider Google for example. Given a search query it returns you 10 most relevant resutls. It never returns you all the Petabytes that match a query. Please note I am not trying to criticize, this are just exactly the same mistakes I did earlier on.

Comment: I understand you're not trying to criticize and I appreciate the help.  When I say "large" datagrid, I am not talking number of rows.  I am talking about footers with totals and multiple groupings (it's a telerik grid).  Pagination won't help this issue.  The grids have been optimized as much as is possible (a telerik support session has confirmed this).  It's takes about .75 - 1.25 seconds to load each grid and I've got five of them.  The userbase has unanimously stated that they want all grids to load at once, rather than experience a delay by having them load when they switch tabs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a catch-22.  If you had some code that you could run to determine that the UI thread was blocked, then you wouldn't be able to start an animation because the UI thread is blocked; the animation wouldn't be shown until after the UI thread finished the tasks it had been working on, at which point the animation is no longer relevant.

In virtually all cases you should be moving your long running tasks to another background thread, not doing them in the UI thread.  You can explicitly disable some/all of the controls on your form at the start of such tasks and enable them at the end.  I would  *highly* discourage you from blocking the UI thread as a means of disabling the form as, from a user perspective, it will appear as if the program isn't working due to a programming bug, as opposed to thinking it's desired behavior.

Comment: My animation is a separate exe that's set to be always on top.  So even if the UI thread is consumed, the animation starts and stops immeadiately and animates properly.  I do often run long running tasks in background threads, but quite often, I don't want the user to be doing anything while there is processing occurring, because I also have datagrids reloading and controls updating, etc. so they shouldn't be able to interact with the UI.

Comment: @Nullqwerty Then just explicitly disable the UI, as I said.  Even if you disable data grids, and buttons, etc. it's *really* annoying, as a user, to not be able to do something like move the window, exit the program, minimize the application, select some text from the page, etc. because it's frozen.  Disable what you need to, and leave the rest.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I do that actually.  That's not my problem.  My question is, how do I detect the state of the UI thread because I'd like to have the animation automatically start and stop?

Comment: @Nullqwerty And I'm saying that any time your UI thread is blocked for long enough for a human to notice it is a failure of your application and should be fixed so that it doesn't happen, rather than dynamically displaying a spinner.

Comment: My datagrids have to get loaded.  Each datagrid takes just over 1 second to bind, which isn't bad considering there are totals and groupings (it's a telerik grid).  There are 6 grids, so about five seconds.  The UI doesn't freeze or stop responding or do anything bad.  That is not my problem.  If you don't know the answer to my question, thanks anyway.

Comment: If your data grids take that long to load you have a problem; they shouldn't be taking that long.  If you just have a lot of data, then you should probably be paging them so that you are only actually loading a small number at a time.  If you don't have an excessive amount of rows then chances are you're doing processing work when data binding that you can/should be pre-computing in the background thread.

Comment: I've already had a 3 week long support session with telerik over it.  By their own admission, adding footers with totals and then putting groupings on them takes a long time.  I've optimized as much as is possible (which they agree with).

Comment: @Nullqwerty It's not a question of how long it takes from the start of the request to when it's ready for user interaction, it's ensuring that 99% of that work takes place in a background thread.  You ought to figure out how to move the work from the UI to the background, rather than just letting the UI be frozen.

Comment: Yes, that's done.  The only code that is in the UI thread is the initial start of the background threads, then once notified that those are complete, the UI thread binds to the updated objects.  The binding takes .75-1.25 seconds to complete per grid due to the footers, totals, groupings, and footer groupings.  I offered an option to the userbase to only load the grid on the current tab, and load the other grids as they switch tabs.  They unanimously agreed they want them all loaded at once rather than experiencing a delay when switching tabs.  I agree with them.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Nullqwerty And my point is that you can compute the totals, groupings, etc. in a background thread, rather than the UI thread, to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: No, I actually do not have control over that.  I just tell the telerik grid to add footers with sum totals, and to group it on certain columns.  It's possible they side load whatever they can to a background task.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add a task to the main UI thread with a really low priority, through the application's `Dispatcher`:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)StopAnimation, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

...

private void StopAnimation()
{
    ...
}
```

This basically says "When the main UI thread has absolutely nothing better to do, call StopAnimation()". The trick is to find the right time to call `.BeginInvoke` - just before or during the grid loading.